# solving this relation using the Recurrence method?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I don't know how to continue in this recurrence cause I don't see any pattern, any help??

```
T(n) = 2n + T(n/2)
     = 3n + T(n/4)
     = 7n/2 + T(n/8)
     = 15n/4 + T(n/16)
     and so on...
```

Comment: What is `n` ? Why there are 4 formulas ? May be you need to solve 4 different cases ?

Comment: `15n/2` should be `15n/4`

Comment: The relation is T(n)= 2n + T(n/2) but I repeat it 3 times using recurrence method

Comment: The pattern is more obvious if you replace `2n` by `1n/0.5`, then it goes `an/b + T(n/c)` -> `(2a+1)n/2b + T(n/2c)`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it's just simple reccurence.

```
T(n) = 2n + T(n/2)
```

Your notation can makes someone think different. For me it should be:

```
T(n) = 2n + T(n/2)                                    ....(1)
T(n/2) = 2(n/2) + T(n/2/2) = n + T(n/4)
T(n) = 2n + n + T(n/4) = 3n + T(n/4)                  ....(2)
T(n/4) = 2(n/4) + T(n/4/2) = n/2 + T(n/8)
T(n) = 2n + n + n/2 + T(n/8) = 7n/2 + T(n/8)          ....(3)
T(n/8) = 2(n/8) + T(n/8/2) = n/4 + T(n/16)
T(n) = 2n + n + n/2 + n/4 + T(n/16) = 15n/4 + T(n/16) ....(4)
T(n/16) = 2(n/16) + T(n/16/2) = n/8 + T(n/32)
T(n) = 15n/4 + n/8 + T(n/32) = 31n/4 + T(n/32)        ....(5)
and so on...
```

Comment: This recurrence will call itself infinitely. Do you need to implement it or do you need to reach result for specific n-value?

Answer (score 0):

This is a usual recurrence relation - if you are a CS student, you will soon know the result by heart.

If you want to find the result by hand, make a geometric sum appears from the recurrence:

```
T(n) = 2n + n + n/2 + ... + n/2^(k+1) + T(0)
     = 2n(1 + 1/2+ ... + 1/2^(k+2)) + T(0)
```

Where `k = INT(log2(n))`

You can see a geometric sum of general term `1/2` appears

```
1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/2^(k+2) = (1 - 1/2^(k+3)) / (1 - 1/2)
```

Observing that `2^(k+2) = 8 * 2^(log2(n)) = 8n` and simplifying

```
T(n) = 4n + T(0) - 1/2 = Theta(4n)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the expanding series till T(0) way shown by Alexandre Dupriez, You can also apply master theorem to solve it

For the recurrence equation

```
T(n) = 2n + T(n/2)
```

**Master Theorem:**

For recurrences of form,

```
T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)

where a >= 1 and b > 1
```

If f(n) is O(n<sup>c</sup>) then

1. If c < log<sub>b</sub>a, then T(n) = O(n * log<sub>b</sub>a)
2. If c = log<sub>b</sub>a, then T(n) = O(n<sup>c</sup> * log n)
3. if c > log<sub>b</sub>a, then T(n) = O(n<sup>c</sup>)

we have a = 1, b = 2, c = 1 and c > log<sub>b</sub>a (case 3)[as c = 1 and log 1 (any base) = 0]

Therefore, T(n) = O (n<sup>1</sup>)

> T(n) = O (n)